# Compiling works, starting not - "standard path"?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++, sfml

I want to use SFML with C++ under Ubuntu OS. I create two debug/release shared Libarys with cmake ([by this tutorial](http://sfmlcoder.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/building-sfml-2-0-with-make-for-gcc/))

I can compile and link my test application without giving any information about a path. So I think everything is alright with the standard path

> g++ -c main.cpp
>
> g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

but when I start now my application with ./sfml-app it said

> ./sfml-app: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libsfml-graphics.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

this confusing me. Because I think /usr/local/lib is the standard path and when I add this path during compiling

> g++ main.o -o sfml-app -L /usr/local/lib  -lsfml-graphics
>   -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

it works. But it should work also without giving information with -L

So what could be the Problem? I have made this before reinstalling Ubuntu. And on my old system it works well, can start my application by ./ terminal and also double clicking.

when I add in the console

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib

I can start the application from the console. but only in the specific one. I want the application starts always also by double click (not only from terminal).  How can I add the Libary "systemwide" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `/usr/local/lib` to a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and then call `ldconfig` to rebuild its cache.

One way of doing it:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usrlocal'
sudo ldconfig
```

Then you should be able to compile without `-L /usr/local/lib` nor use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib`.